# Error in String.replaceAll() function

Tags: java

I am trying the following code:-

```
String x = "asdfg/dgws";
x.replaceAll("/", "\\");
```

But this is failing. This is giving me the following error message:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.jai.SecLargest.main(SecLargest.java:13)
```

I am not able to figure out why this exception is coming?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`String.replaceAll` ends up using (or being equivalent to using) [`Matcher.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29), which includes this in the documentation:

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences as described above, and backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement string.

While you *could* escape the backslash as per AlexR's answer, I would strongly recommend that you use `replace` instead:

```
String y = x.replace('/', '\\');
```

That's a lot clearer, IMO - don't use `replaceAll` unless you're really *trying* to express a pattern via regular expressions.

Also note that *as written* your code would be a no-op anyway; strings are immutable in Java, so the `replaceAll` method (and similar ones) return a reference to a *new* string with the modificiations made.

Answer (score 8):

You should say `x.replaceAll("/", "\\\\");`

Back slash `\` must be escaped twice: once of regular expressions engine and once for java itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [quoteReplacement()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)) method, in case you really need a regex.